# how to output what i type in a textbox using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<form:form
    action="/hospital/login.html" 
    method="post">
        User name: <form:input name="un" path="username"/> <br/>
        password: <form:password path="password"/><br/>
<c:out value="${ un }" />
</form:form>
```

i dont want to use any scriplets since i am programming a servlet using spring mvc,  but i want to display simultaneously what i type inside the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take some action simultaneously, without posting the form, then you will be needing client side scripting with Javascript.

A very simple and pure Javascript way to achieve what you want is as below.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<form:form
    action="/hospital/login.html" 
    method="post">
        User name: <form:input name="un" path="username" onkeyUp="javascript:sync()" /> <br/>
        password: <form:password path="password"/><br/>
<span id='outLabel'></span>
</form:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sync()
{
  var textbox = document.getElementsByName('un')[0];
  var label = document.getElementById('outLabel');
  label.textContent = textBox.value;
} 
</script>
```

You can play with JSFiddle example of client side part [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3vvtwtpf/).

You can improve this in multiple ways: using `id` for `form:input`, using jquery to selecting dom elements more easily, including javascript part from a js file are all things you should consider for a better design.